# Происхождение слова "привет"

Tags: этимология

Обычное слово, которое употребляется сто раз на дню, но каково его происхождение?

Comment: Вот у Даля нашел по слову Привечать:
...Приветствие, стар. приветство ср. приветствование или приветливость; самая речь, слова привечающего кого-либо, или привет м. всякое доброе пожелание, благосклонный прием, ласковое, дружелюбное слово при встрече, радушное здравствование. Не мудрен привет, а сердца покоряет. Каков привет, таков и ответ. Без привету нет ответу. По привету ответ держат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Родственно "совет", "ответ" и т. д.
"...вѣтъ" - общеславянский морф с примерным значением "речь", "слово" - точное значение, судя по всему, утеряно. От него же (через "вѣтити" – " говорить", "обращаться"), происходит и "вития" - хороший оратор, краснобай.

Comment: Да, судя по всему, связано это с речью. От-вет, это вроде как действие от себя, а привет, видимо к себе, как при-влечение.

Answer (score 0):

Произошло от ПИЕ ***u̯oq̆s*** "речь, голос"

Answer (score -2):

В старые времена, когда славяне шли в гости, они брали с собой веточку ели, веточку березы и веточку дуба. Каждая имела свой смысл: дубовая - пожелание крепости духа, березовая - здоровья (банного духа), веточка ели (сосны) - даров и богатства (в лесу грибы, ягоды и т. д.). Это и называлось ПРИВЕТВИЕМ впоследствии трансформировалось в ПРИВЕТСТВИЕ. Так что, говоря приветствую, подразумевается *дарю тебе три блага.*